# Regex Capture not equal to String of equal value

Tags: android, regex

Both strings appear to be the same when printed to the console, but not when compared using "=="

What am i doing wrong here?

```
String message = "Rejected | Ref ID: CaptureMe | Name:";  

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bRef ID:\\s+(\\S+)");     

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);

String matchedRef = matcher.group(1); 
System.out.print(matchedRef);
```

***Prints: CaptureMe***

```
String myRef = "CaptureMe";

if(matchedRef == myRef){
System.out.print(true);
}
else{
System.out.print(false);
}
```

***Prints: FALSE***

Comment: Change `matchedRef == myRef` to `matchedRef.equals(myRef)`

Answer (score 2):

To compare strings you need to use the [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method, not the `==` operator.

```
if(matchedRef.equals(myRef)){
    System.out.print(true);
}
else{
    System.out.print(false);
}
```

You can read more about `String` comparisons in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: So simple. Thank you